# Uncaught TypeError when using Bootstrap with VueJS

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, typeerror

I am trying to integrate bootstrap with my vue project, but when I open my browser, my console gives the following error.

```
config.js?228e:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at eval (config.js?228e:8)
    at Module../node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/utils/config.js (chunk-vendors.js:3262)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (alert.js?5fda:1)
    at Module../node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/components/alert/alert.js (chunk-vendors.js:94)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (index.js?cca8:1)
    at Module../node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/components/alert/index.js (chunk-vendors.js:106)
```

I ran `$ vue add bootstrap-vue` which created `bootstrap-vue.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
```

Vue Version: 3

Bootstrap Version: 4

Any suggestions on how to fix this error or install bootstrap on vue?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As per this [Github issue](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/5196) and per their [Vue-Bootstrap documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs) it is currently not possible to use Vue3.x with Bootstrap since there are some major breaking changes.

[This is mentioned](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/5196#issuecomment-628892074) in the issue:

> Note there are quite a few breaking changes between Vue 2.x and Vue
> 3.x, which will need changes in BootstrapVue.
>
> Vue.extend, which is used extensively, is not available in Vue 3.x.
> (it is replaced with createComponent() method exported by Vue 3.x)
>
> You might be able to import Vue and createComponent first, and then
> set Vue.export = createComponent, and then import the 3rd party
> libraries (like PortalVue, BootstrapVue, etc).